# MacOS kernel, .kext and devices in /dev

Tags: macos, kernel, driver, hardware, kernel-extension

I got a trouble with my USB 3G modem, i do a debugging, but i cannot determine what .kext file create a device in /dev

How to determine relationship between device file in /dev (like /dev/usbdriver.001) and .kext?

Answer (score 0):

To create a /dev entry a Kext would normally use IOxxxBSDClient (e.g. Serial, Media, etc). You can use ioreg -l, and look for it, like so:

```
... (this would be the parent class) ...
|   +-o IOSerialBSDClient  <class IOSerialBSDClient, id 0x100000385, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 5>
      | |       {
      | |         "IOClass" = "IOSerialBSDClient"
      | |         "CFBundleIdentifier" = "com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily"
      | |         "IOProviderClass" = "IOSerialStreamSync"
      | |         "IOTTYBaseName" = "Bluetooth-Serial-1"
      | |         "IOSerialBSDClientType" = "IORS232SerialStream"
      | |         "IOProbeScore" = 1000
      | |         "IOCalloutDevice" = "/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Serial-1"
      | |         "IODialinDevice" = "/dev/tty.Bluetooth-Serial-1"
      | |         "IOMatchCategory" = "IODefaultMatchCategory"
      | |         "IOTTYDevice" = "Bluetooth-Serial-1"
      | |         "IOResourceMatch" = "IOBSD"
      | |         "IOTTYSuffix" = ""
      | |       }
```

And that usually does the trick.